# Flask button not getting detected

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask

What's wrong with my button click detector?

```
$('.start2').on('click', function() {
```

and here is the button

```
<button class="start2">START</button>
```

Comment: Could you explain more you problem ?

Answer (score 3):

Nothing wrong you should just pass a callback function doing what you want,

**Example**:

```js
$('.start2').on('click', function() {

  console.log("hello")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="start2">START</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

From What I can see you are missing }

```
$('.start2').on('click', function() {
  console.log('clicked!!!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
socket.on('connect', function() {
    socket.send('Admin connected');
});
```

```
$('.start2').on('click', function() {
    socket.send('dxdd');
});
```

The first function works, the second one doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make it **do** something when it's clicked.

```
<button class="start2" onclick="return funcName(input_you_can_choose_to_not_have_it);">START</button>
```

Then you just need to add the code when the function (funcName) is called.
Like (In Javascript):

```
<script>
</script>
```

```
<script>
  var notLocal = null; // No need to add it

  var funcName = function (input) {
    var localVarible = input;
    notLocal = input + " RAN THIS PROJECT!!!";
    //Haha it was just a joke
    console.log("Something else...");
    console.log(notLocal);
    //Do more!!!
  };
</script>
```

Did it help?